# Plot lines for unique label in col - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to pass a function that plots various objects for each unique label. Using the df below, `A-D` are used to plot various objects. I then pass each unique value in `label` to the function.

I'm hoping to pass something more efficient that calling the function on each unique item in a list. Iterating through the list to produce a separate figure for each unique value in `label`. Using below, this should be 3 `(X,Y,Z)`.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 import random

def plot(dfs, label):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for l in label:

        df = dfs[dfs['label'] == l]

        x1 = df['A']
        y1 = df['B']

        x2 = df['C']
        y2 = df['D']

        plt.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'orange', marker = 'o', zorder = 3)
        plt.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green', marker = 'o', zorder = 2)

        ax.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1) 

    plt.show()  

np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
labels = df['A'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z']) ) 
df['label'] = labels

unq_label = df['label'].unique()

figs = df.groupby('label').apply(plot,unq_label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@r-beginners has already solved the problem. In my post, I will also solve it using the same (maybe the only) way but with another `Dataframe` for better visualization.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def plot(dfs, label):
    
    label = sorted(label)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=len(label),figsize=(12,6))

    for ind,l in enumerate(label):

        df = dfs[dfs['label'] == l]

        x1 = df['A']
        y1 = df['B']

        x2 = df['C']
        y2 = df['D']

        ax[ind].scatter(x1, y1, c = 'orange', marker = 'o', zorder = 3,)
        ax[ind].scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green', marker = 'o', zorder = 2,)
        ax[ind].plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1,)
        ax[ind].set_title('class %s' % l)
        ax[ind].set_ylim(-11,21)

    plt.show()  

np.random.seed(2020)
x,y,z = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)),np.random.randint(-10,0,size=(5, 4)),np.random.randint(10,20,size=(5, 4)),
data = np.vstack((x,y,z))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'))
df['label'] = ['X'] *5 + ['Y'] * 5 + ['Z'] * 5

unq_label = df['label'].unique()
plot(df, unq_label)
```

The output figure is

[image: output]

---

**UPDATE**

In order to plot different labels in different figures, not subplots, you can try the code below. The idea is to create a new figure for each label.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def plot(dfs, label):
    
    label = sorted(label)
    for ind,l in enumerate(label):
        
        fig = plt.figure(ind)
        df = dfs[dfs['label'] == l]

        x1 = df['A']
        y1 = df['B']

        x2 = df['C']
        y2 = df['D']

        plt.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'orange', marker = 'o', zorder = 3,)
        plt.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green', marker = 'o', zorder = 2,)
        plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1,)
        plt.title('class %s' % l)
        plt.ylim(-11,21)

        plt.show()  

np.random.seed(2020)
x,y,z = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)),np.random.randint(-10,0,size=(5, 4)),np.random.randint(10,20,size=(5, 4)),
data = np.vstack((x,y,z))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'))
df['label'] = ['X'] *5 + ['Y'] * 5 + ['Z'] * 5

unq_label = df['label'].unique()
plot(df, unq_label)
```

Comment: I hoping to produce output figures. So a separate figure for each unique label. Not separate subplots within the single figure.

Comment: this is what I was after `df.groupby('label').apply(plot,unq_label)`

Comment: @jonboy I understand, see my updated post, the idea is to create a new figure for each unique label.

Answer (score 1):

As the question has evolved, I have modified the code for the current issue. `axes[]` to make it an array. Is this as intended?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def plot(dfs, label):

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)

    for i,l in enumerate(label):

        df = dfs[dfs['label'] == l]

        x1 = df['A']
        y1 = df['B']

        x2 = df['C']
        y2 = df['D']

        axes[i].scatter(x1, y1, c = 'orange', marker = 'o', zorder = 3)
        axes[i].scatter(x2, y2, c = 'green', marker = 'o', zorder = 2)

        axes[i].plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1) 
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    plt.show()  

np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
labels = df['A'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z']) ) 
df['label'] = labels

unq_label = df['label'].unique()
plot(df, unq_label)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line: `ax.plot([Ax,Cx],[By,Dy], color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1)`. `Error: KeyError: 0`

Comment: `print(df)` to see if the data exists. In that case, it's easier to debug if you set `np.random.seed(2020)` before the random number is generated. It doesn't generate an error in my environment. Did you copy all the code?

Comment: Yep, data exists. I've put in the seed. I think it's the number of items per label. If I bump up the df length to 1000 values it works. But I'm hoping to plot individual figures for each unique label.

Comment: I'm not sure how the situation changes with the number of data. Also, if you want to label it, you can give it to it with `ax.text()` or `ax.annotate()`, but if it's a large number, it may make the graph more confusing.